# How to import OSM ways, without tags, into PostgreSQL using osm2pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have a particular problem when importing OSM Data with osm2pgsql.

I have been searching for days on how to import ways, which do not have any tag, but which are part of a relation (which itself has tags), into PostgreSQL.

Take the following way for example: http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/50126690

As you can see it does not have any tags, but is part of the relation, http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2648656#map=15/47.6481/12.3246 which is tagged as a cross country slope.

When I import the data into postgresql, the way `50126690` is not imported. Even when I use `hstore` option, which should keep all objects, (if you believe documentation on http://www.volkerschatz.com/net/osm/osm2pgsql-usage.html) the way will not be imported into `planet_osm_line` table.

My `default.style` looks like the snippet at the bottom.

Can anybody point me into the right direction on how to import those ways?

```
OsmType    Tag          DataType     Flags
node,way   access       text         linear
node,way   addr:housename      text  linear
node,way   addr:housenumber    text  linear
node,way   addr:interpolation  text  linear
node,way   admin_level  text         linear
node,way   aerialway    text         linear
node,way   aeroway      text         polygon
node,way   amenity      text         polygon
node,way   area         text         polygon # hard coded support for area=1/yes => polygon is in osm2pgsql
node,way   barrier      text         linear
node,way   bicycle      text         linear
node,way   brand        text         linear
node,way   bridge       text         linear
node,way   boundary     text         linear
node,way   building     text         polygon
node       capital      text         linear
node,way   construction text         linear
node,way   covered      text         linear
node,way   culvert      text         linear
node,way   cutting      text         linear
node,way   denomination text         linear
node,way   disused      text         linear
node       ele          text         linear
node,way   embankment   text         linear
node,way   foot         text         linear
node,way   generator:source    text  linear
node,way   harbour      text         polygon
node,way   highway      text         linear
node,way   historic     text         polygon
node,way   horse        text         linear
node,way   intermittent text         linear
node,way   junction     text         linear
node,way   landuse      text         polygon
node,way   layer        text         linear
node,way   leisure      text         polygon
node,way   lock         text         linear
node,way   man_made     text         polygon
node,way   military     text         polygon
node,way   motorcar     text         linear
node,way   name         text         linear
node,way   natural      text         polygon  # natural=coastline tags are discarded by a hard coded rule in osm2pgsql
node,way   office       text         polygon
node,way   oneway       text         linear
node,way   operator     text         linear
node,way   place        text         polygon
node       poi          text         linear
node,way   population   text         linear
node,way   power        text         polygon
node,way   power_source text         linear
node,way   public_transport text     polygon
node,way   railway      text         linear
node,way   ref          text         linear
node,way   religion     text         linear
node,way   route        text         linear
node,way   service      text         linear
node,way   shop         text         polygon
node,way   sport        text         polygon
node,way   surface      text         linear
node,way   toll         text         linear
node,way   tourism      text         polygon
node,way   tower:type   text         linear
way        tracktype    text         linear
node,way   tunnel       text         linear
node,way   water        text         polygon
node,way   waterway     text         polygon
node,way   wetland      text         polygon
node,way   width        text         linear
node,way   wood         text         linear
node,way   z_order      int4         linear # This is calculated during import
way        way_area     real         linear # This is calculated during import
```

## Area tags

We don't make columns for these tags, but objects with them are areas.
Mainly for use with hstore

```
way         abandoned:aeroway       text    phstore
way         abandoned:amenity       text    phstore
way         abandoned:building      text    phstore
way         abandoned:landuse       text    phstore
way         abandoned:power         text    phstore
way         area:highway            text    phstore
```

## Deleted tags

These are tags that are generally regarded as useless for most rendering.
Most of them are from imports or intended as internal information for mappers
Some of them are automatically deleted by editors.
If you want some of them, perhaps for a debugging layer, just delete the lines.

These tags are used by mappers to keep track of data.
They aren't very useful for rendering.

```
node,way    note                    text    delete
node,way    note:*                  text    delete
node,way    source                  text    delete
node,way    source_ref              text    delete
node,way    source:*                text    delete
node,way    attribution             text    delete
node,way    comment                 text    delete
node,way    fixme                   text    delete
```

## Tags generally dropped by editors, not otherwise covered

```
node,way    created_by              text    delete
node,way    odbl                    text    delete
node,way    odbl:note               text    delete
node,way    SK53_bulk:load          text    delete
```

## Lots of import tags

### TIGER (US)

```
node,way    tiger:*                 text    delete
```

### NHD (US)

NHD has been converted every way imaginable

```
node,way    NHD:*                   text    delete
node,way    nhd:*                   text    delete
```

### GNIS (US)

```
node,way    gnis:*                  text    delete
```

### Geobase (CA)

```
node,way    geobase:*               text    delete
```

### NHN (CA)

```
node,way    accuracy:meters         text    delete
node,way    sub_sea:type            text    delete
node,way    waterway:type           text    delete
```

### KSJ2 (JA)

See also `note:ja` and `source_ref` above

```
node,way    KSJ2:*                  text    delete
```

### Yahoo/ALPS (JA)

```
node,way    yh:*                    text    delete
```

### osak (DK)

```
node,way    osak:*                  text    delete
```

### kms (DK)

```
node,way    kms:*                   text    delete
```

### ngbe (ES)

See also `note:es` and `source:file` above

```
node,way    ngbe:*                  text    delete
```

### naptan (UK)

```
node,way    naptan:*                text    delete
```

### Corine (CLC) (Europe)

```
node,way    CLC:*                   text    delete
```

### misc

```
node,way    3dshapes:ggmodelk       text    delete
node,way    AND_nosr_r              text    delete
node,way    import                  text    delete
node,way    it:fvg:*                text    delete
```

### OpenPisteMap data activated

```
way piste:lift      text    linear
way piste:lift:occupancy    text    linear
way piste:lift:capacity text    linear
way piste:lift:duration text    linear
way piste:type      text    linear
way piste:difficulty    text    linear
way     piste:grooming          text    linear
way     piste:ref               text    linear
way     lit                     text    linear
way     aerialway:capacity      text    linear
way     aerialway:duration      text    linear
way     aerialway:heating       text    linear
way     aerialway:bubble        text    linear
way     aerialway:occupancy     text    linear
node,way information            text    linear
way     sac_scale               text    linear
```

If you're interested in bicycle routes, you may want the following fields
To make these work you need slim mode or the necessary data won't be remembered.

```
way       lcn_ref      text     linear
way       rcn_ref      text     linear
way       ncn_ref      text     linear
way       lcn          text     linear
way       rcn          text     linear
way       ncn          text     linear
way       lwn_ref      text     linear
way       rwn_ref      text     linear
way       nwn_ref          text     linear
way       lwn              text     linear
way       rwn              text     linear
way       nwn              text     linear
way       route_pref_color text     linear
way       route_name       text     linear
way       loc_ref      text     linear
way       usage      text     linear
```

Answer (score 1):

Way 50126690 should be imported as a part of the route relation, even not as an independent linestring because as you noticed it as no normal tags which you could select with the default.style. All ways have still some technical tags and I would guess that your way would be imported into osm_lines if you add for example the osm_user tag into your default.style https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql.

Comment: Besides adding the line in the style file, you need to add `--extra-attributes` to your command line, see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Special_.27tags.27